# How is heat of the city of Artemis disposed?

Tags: andy-weir, artemis

In the novel Artemis by Andy Weir it is told that the heat generated by harvester's engine/battery cannot dissolve into the air and rise to the sky because there is no atmosphere. Therefore the heat stays on the heat source and builds up. Which is the reason for some alternative cooling system. Author mentions water and wax (if I recall correctly) which must be periodically changed in the city to allow coolant (water/wax) to cool down.

My question is - how is the heat of the city handled? The city must be hotter than space around the bubbles, which would mean that the heat should build up around the bubbles, right? 
I don't think this is discussed in the book, unless I missed it (foreign speaker).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed it. It was literally in the next passage

> ***Artemis has a complex coolant system that conveys the heat to thermal
>   panels near the reactor complex. They sit in the shade and slowly
>   radiate the energy away as infrared light.*** But the harvesters had to
>   be self-contained.

As to the harvesters, their engines are encased in wax. The wax melts and when they get back to base water is pumped in to cool the wax and the (now heated) water is pumped away to cool back to ambient.

> *“The battery and motor housings are encased in a solid wax reservoir.
>   Melting the wax takes a lot of energy, so that’s where the heat goes.
>   The wax lines are surrounded by coolant pipes. When the harvester
>   comes home to recharge, they pump cold water into those pipes to
>   re-chill the wax, then pull the newly heated water back out. Then they
>   cool the water off at their leisure while the harvester gets back to
>   work.”*

Comment: Oh, I thought the infrared radiation thing was related only to the (waste) heat of the reactors. Thanks a lot!